# Angular 4 and typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i need to validate the textbox which is present in form where i dont want user to enter the spaces initially and it should start with alphanumeric and then we can add spaces in between the text.

i am writing the regex code in typescript but it is not working for me.

i am calling allowAlphaNumeric method on keypress in input control

```
allowAlphaNumeric(event) {
        return event && event.key && event.key.match(this.regExpAlphaNumeric) ? true : false;
    }

<input class="form-control ip-box-css" type="text" formControlName = "campaignName" id="campaignName" (keypress)="allowAlphaNumeric($event)" maxlength="30" placeholder="Enter" required>

where regExpAlphaNumeric: string = '^[^-\s][a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]+$';
```

the issue is that the regex expression is not considering as string

Please provide some suggestion so that it will work in .ts(typescript) file

Comment: you are doing it on keypress ??

Comment: yes i want to achieve it on keypress

Comment: seeems like you got the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a form control (or a control in a formGroup)

```
textboxToValidate: FormControl = new FormControl('', [
  Validators.required,
  Validators.pattern(/^[^-\s][a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]+$/)
]);
```

Those built-in classes can be imported from the form module

```
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: trichetriche : can we achieve this on keypress. i have modified the question.

Comment: Well it's already on keypress, how did you use the form control ?

Comment: can we use       regExpAlphaNumeric: string = '^[^-\s][a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]+$';   

    
campaignName : new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.regExpAlphaNumeric)]),


here in this case regExpAlphaNumeric is string but it is not working

Comment: First things first : do you know what a form control is, and how to use it ?

Comment: yes i will look into this. Actually i am new to angular .thanks